# can I use a SET statement in a Marketing Cloud QUERY?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

I'm trying to write a query that will take unsubscribes from a child BU and write into a shared DE at the parent level.  I know how to find the unsubscribes, but I'm trying to write into a DE field where we store the "status" so I thought I would use a SET statement (SET brand_subscribed = 'false') but I keep getting an error at the SET statement.

Can I use a SET statement in a Query in Marketing Cloud?

I don't want to assign a default value of FALSE as I don't want to accidentally mark someone as unsubscribed if they are in another business unit (all unsubs for the parent are being written into the shared DE).

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce Marketing Cloud queries currently use a *variation* of SQL 2008, and it does not allow some functions; such as SET/UPDATE/DELETE.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you can use [**SQL CASE**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) to check the values from the [**_Subscribers Data View**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/) and write them into a new DE to export.

The following will 'Overwrite' into a new DE containing 3 values 
(Subscriberkey, Status and IsSubscribed):

```
SELECT
allsubs.SubscriberKey
,allsubs.Status
,CASE
    WHEN allsubs.Status = 'ACTIVE'
    THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
    END as 'IsSubscribed'
FROM [_Subscribers] allsubs
```

Comment: Thanks, Cameron!  I gave it a go, and while the syntax was correct it never ended up writing to the ENT.DE that I selected... so, back to plan A (which is really a plan B!) of importing into a DE with a default value of "FALSE" and moving that data around.

Comment: Hey @GeorgeRosedale, post a new question and include your query (and **as much detail as possible**) and the community can try to help you.

Comment: Here's what I tried: 

    `SELECT 
SubscriberKey as email, 
DateUnsubscribed as BMT_unsubscribe_date, 
Status, 
     CASE WHEN Status = 'UNSUBSCRIBED' 
     THEN 'FALSE' 
      ELSE 'TRUE' END as 'BMT_subscribed' 

FROM _Subscribers

WHERE 
DATEPART(mm,DateUnsubscribed) = DATEPART(mm,DateAdd(d,-1,GetDate())) AND DATEPART(dd,DateUnsubscribed) = DATEPART(dd,DateAdd(d,-1,GetDate())) AND DATEPART(yyyy,DateUnsubscribed) = DATEPART(yyyy,DateAdd(d,-1,GetDate()))`

Comment: Were you able to make it work George? You can try using a BETWEEN operator in your WHERE clause to make it easier. See: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can not use any update statements in marketing cloud query activity but if your only goal is to collect unsubscribes from BU to a shared DE then I am not sure where you are actually getting this problem as you can simply use _subscribers data view and get subscribers data in to result DE.

[_subscriber data view](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  What I'd like to do is change a value from TRUE to FALSE for the export (which is how sub flags are stored outside of MC)